# How to account for errors in the ajax calls when using alternative promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I've developed the code below (also available in this codepen http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/QNVEbP) when building an app that will provide weather data depending on user's location coordinates.

User's location will be delivered by the `getCoordinatesMethod1()` function. However if this fails, the location should be delivered by the `getCoordinatesMethod2()` function.

How can I add the `getCoordinatesMethod2()` to the the promises chain (at the bottom) so that it only is used when `getCoordinatesMethod1()` fails to deliver the location?

Also, in future in order to make the app more robust I may add further methods to fetch location data so the chain logic should be able to accommodate that as well.

```
// The first method to get user location coordinates.
function getCoordinatesMethod1() {
  return $.ajax('http://wwww.example.com/coordinates-method-1.json');
}

// The second method to get user location coordinates.
// This should only be used if method 1 fails to deliver coordinates.
function getCoordinatesMethod2() {
  return $.ajax('http://wwww.example.com/coordinates-method-2.json');
}

// Function which provides weather data depending on user coordinates.
function getCurrentWeather(latitude, longitude) {
  return $.ajax('http://www.example.com/lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + 'weather.json');
}

// Promises chain
getUserCoordinates1().then(function(locationData) {
  return getCurrentWeather(locationData);
  }).then(function(weatherData) {
    return showCurrentWeather(weatherData);
  })
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery 3 or an earlier version with broken promises?

Comment: At the moment I'm using jQuery 2.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that calls the first method and, if the returns promise rejects, then calls the second method:

```
function getCoordinateBoth() {
   return getCoordinatesMethod1().then(null, getCoordinatesMethod2);
}
```

If there are actually arguments passed to these functions, then you can pass those arguments on like this:

```
function getCoordinateBoth(/* args here */) {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
   return getCoordinatesMethod1.apply(null, args).then(null, function() {
       return getCoordinatesMethod2.apply(null, args)    
   });
}
```

You could even just have these functions in an array so it is infinitely extensible:

```
// Put list of functions to be call as a chain until one succeeds
// You can just add more functions here as long as each returns a promise
//    and expects the same arguments
var getCoordFunctions = [getCoordinatesMethod1, getCoordinateMethod2, getCoordinateMethod3];

function getCoordinateChain(/* args here */) {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
   var fnArray = getCoordFunctions.slice(0);
   var firstFn = fnArray.shift();
   fnArray.reduce(function(p, fn) {
        return p.then(null, function() {
            return fn.apply(null, args);
        });
   }, firstFn.apply(null, arguments));
}
```

You could even make this a generic promise chain function:

```
function chainUntilResolve(array /* other args here */) {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
   // toss first arg
   args.shift();
   // make a copy of array of functions
   var fnArray = array.slice(0);
   // remove first function from the array
   var firstFn = fnArray.shift();
   fnArray.reduce(function(p, fn) {
        return p.then(null, function() {
            return fn.apply(null, args);
        });
   }, firstFn.apply(null, arguments));
}


var getCoordFunctions = [getCoordinatesMethod1, getCoordinateMethod2, getCoordinateMethod3];

chainUntilResolve(getCoordFunctions, arg1, arg2).then(function(data) {
    // process data here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```